# Using Range in Python expression of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

what is the python expression for defining a range of numbers?

I have tried numerous combinations but cannot get a simple range of angles (100 -200) to compute correctly.

Screen shot :

[image: Range in Field Calculator needed]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if !ET_Angle! > 100 and !ET_Angle! < 200
```

To be more complete, put this in the codeblock:

```
def LeftOrRight(value):
    if value > 100 and value < 200:
         return "LEFT"
    else:
         return "RIGHT"
```

And in the calculation area, just put:

```
LeftOrRight(!ET_Angle!)
```

Comment: So many people ignore the codeblock. It can be very powerful.

Comment: I think they ignore it because the term "code" is rather intimidating unless you are familiar with the language.

Comment: Awesome! That's just what we needed! Much Thanks!!

Comment: You got it. Sometimes a few examples can make things clearer.

Comment: i always save these code solutions and i tried using previously saved codeblocks for this today, but needed further schooling on formulating range expressions... not really intimidated by python just exacerbated sometimes due to time constraints and lack of Google-Fu when looking for the answers... GSE is always a great help for filling in the gaps with Google-Fu .