# Doing If/Then over multiple data columns in Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have some VB code saved that looks at two columns of data, and populates a third with the low value.

Pre-logic Script Code:

```
Dim output as double
if [MIN_LEFT] < [MIN_RIGHT] Then
  output = [MIN_LEFT]
else
  output = [MIN_RIGHT]
end if

low = output
```

I've never used Python before, but I see that I'm going to have to if I want to do this calculation!  But I'm stumped by the comparison of the two columns, and how to define that.  Can anyone help me? (And I apologize if this is overly basic!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you want to do in the codeblock for Python is define a function, and then call the function using your attributes as parameters as follows:

```
def comparison(left,right):
    if left < right:
        return left
    else:
        return right

output = comparison(!MIN_LEFT!,!MIN_RIGHT!)
```

Then, all you need in the calculation is `output`, as you already had for VBScript.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is somewhat similar to [Using Range in Python expression of ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11078)

As you can see, declaring functions is a rather different affair in Python, and you are not required to denote types (such as double) ahead of time.

You should look into the Calculate Field examples in the [resource center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) to give you a good idea of what your syntax looks like.

Important points:

- Fields are denoted with double exclamation marks (like !MIN_LEFT!).
- In the expression, you can call the function and create a variable with the returned value (as @nmpeterson shows), or return it directly from the function by putting the function call in the expression box.
- Be careful with indentation, as it is how functions and control blocks (if/else) are identified.

I would definitely recommend you look up the nuts and bolts of python functions. They are quite simple to start and will do you a lot of good in the future if you get them down now.

Answer (score 6):

For this simple example, you can use an inline-if statement (does not require codeblock):

```
!MIN_LEFT! if !MIN_LEFT! < !MIN_RIGHT! else !MIN_RIGHT!
```

For more complicated logic (e.g., if-elif-...), use a `def` and codeblock.