# Writing conditional (if/then) statements into ArcGIS Field Calculator using Python Parser?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, python-parser, if-else

I have gotten stuck on seemingly simple ArcGIS field calculator python expression.

I obtained a great answer to a another similar question a few years ago: [Using Range in Python expression of ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11078/python-field-calculator-arcgis-10-expression-for-a-range).
Now I need to populate a new field based on 6 ranges of values (bedrock depth).

My attempt at writing this expression is below:

[image]

I just need to populate the empty field "bedrockdp" using the ranges in the toc called brockdepmin.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEmEH.png)

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def !GRIDCODE! (value):
    if value >0 and value < 50:
        return "0 - 50 cm from the surface"
    else:
        return "n/a"
```

bedrockdep =

```
GRIDCODE (!bedrockdep!)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the problem lies with your statement:

```
def !gridcode! (value):
```

is incorrect, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000

```
def something(value):
```

It's hard to read what you've got there but I think this is it:
[image: Python expression]

Full expression:

```
def TextValue(FromCode):
    if FromCode > 0 and FromCode < 50:
        return "0 - 50 cm from the surface"
    elif FromCode < 150:
        return "101 - 150 cm"
    elif FromCode < 200:
        return "151 - 200 cm"
    elif FromCode < 250:
        return "201 - 250 cm"
    elif FromCode < 1000:
        return "251 - 1000 cm"
    else:
        return "N/A"
```

This will populate the text that is in the legend using the GRIDCODE as the numeric source.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JEmEH.png is link to the screenshot

Comment: Fair enough, the problem is that you're using !gridcode! as the function name. The field *bedrockdepmin* is the one that gets the exclamation marks. It has to do with the scope of the variable.. only the lower box allows substitution, the pre-logic code deals only with variables and the return value is what is populated into the selected field. I can't see the field that you are using to calculate from *brockdepmin* in the screenshot, is it there? or is it the GRIDCODE?

Comment: GRIDCODE is the only value from the attribute table being used. The toc has the 6 classes that need to be added to the bedrockdep field based on the GRIDCODE field. I will give your code a shot in the morning and post the results here. THANKS

Comment: good answer, but I recommend using the parentheses in the condition: if (FromCode > 0) and (FromCode < 50):

Comment: okay, it's running but only populating bedrockdep field with "N/A". Not sure how to post code in threads <cntl + k> { } ?? Here's the paste of the Pre-Logic:  def GRIDCODE(FromCode):
    if (FromCode > 0) and (FromCode < 50):
        return "0 - 50 cm from the surface"
    elif (FromCode < 150):
        return "101 - 150 cm"
    elif (FromCode < 200):
        return "151 - 200 cm"
    elif (FromCode < 250):
        return "201 - 250 cm"
    elif (FromCode < 1000):
        return "251 - 1000 cm"
    else:
        return "N/A"

Comment: screen shot here: http://i.imgur.com/8UQD8l9.png

Comment: S O L U T I O N  http://i.imgur.com/I7ijD9F.png  I forgot to replace FromCode with GRIDCODE. It is working! Just one last thing how do you write greater OR EQUAL ?

Comment: >= is the operator for greater or equal.

Comment: @radouxju I used to put the parenthesis around the conditions, sort of 'C' style but got pinged because they were unnecessary. I like them, and use them in my own code, they help to isolate the if statement and contribute to the readability.

Comment: @>= is the operator for greater or equal. –  Michael Miles-Stimson Thanks a bunch! Do you know of list for commonly needed python field calculator expressions?... Something not like the Esri help web pages would be ideal; just concise easy to follow list using examples like the code you provided above.

Comment: The link http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000004s000000 provided in the answer is a basic tutorial, about half way down is a nice picture on how to use the field calculator. Unlike the VB field calculator expressions the python function list is just *python*, though I don't know about importing specific modules like sys, os, math, if you go here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/  to get a tutorial of the basics of python (not arcpy).