# Calculating Field from text to integer using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm using ArcGIS 10.7 trying to calculate a speed field (for my data of roads in California) really simply such that roads = 45 and highways = 65. I know I need to use an if then statement but I'm not too familiar with Python or ArcGIS so I need a function that will allow me to say if the text string includes "FWY" OR "HWY" OR "RTE" return 65 and else = 45. Does anyone know how I could get this done? I'm fine computing with some error as its for an intro class.

[image: image of data I'm working with of streets in California]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would expect that a question like this has been asked and answered on this site previously.

Comment: You'll learn a lot more if you break open the documentation and review the examples in Calculate Field which cover cases *very* similar to this. It's quite likely GIS SE won't want to get a reputation for doing homework for those unwilling to at least try to do it themselves.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked multiple times here before.   Please try a field calculator config based on any of them, then if you can't get it working, update your question (or ask a new one) showing what you've tried.  Eg:  [Basic If/Then in Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81817/basic-if-then-in-python-parser-of-arcgis-field-calculator), [conditional statements in ArcGIS Field Calculator using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99615/writing-conditional-if-then-statements-into-arcgis-field-calculator-using-pyth)

Comment: For your specific case, you may want to try a code block that defines a function that includes an `if` statement like, `if "FWY" in upperName or "HWY" in upperName or "RTE" in upperName:` (and before that you'd need to define `upperName` as the uppercase equivalent of fullname, something like, `upperName = fullname.upper()`.