# Constructing distribution graphs of attribute tables using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, graph, distribution

Since I'm new to python I have an issue with writing the correct code to achieve the following. The picture is an example of an attribute table of which i want to make frequency distribution graphs according to certain ranges of an indicator variable.
For instance a graph should be created in which the range of ORG_STOF (indicator variable) should be: < 2, 2 - 3.5, etc. for which the Count_ORG_STOF needs to be indicated.

According to another question post i found ([Using Range in Python expression of ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11078/using-range-in-python-expression-of-arcgis-field-calculator)) 
I thought that a solution would be something in the line of:
Additional fields should be created for each range (in most cases consisting of 3 or 5)

```
    def "Range_one"(value):
    if value > 2 and value < 3.5:
     return "Value of Count_ORG"
     else:
     return "0"
```

Then in the calculation area:

```
    Range_one(!ORG_STOF!)
```

However, it is a bit different in my case, since in the solution script I had in mind I need to refer to two fields.

[image: After trial]

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177652/calculate-field-more-wisely/177654#177654. It does reclassify for you. You'll need to summarise any field in original table, which will give you a frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the expression below

```
def "Range_one"(value1,value2):
    if value > 2 and value < 3.5:
        return value2
    else:
        return 0
```

With this call

```
Range_one (!ORG_STOF!,!Count_ORG_STOF!)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your adequate response. However, I have tried to copy the script that you wrote but I did not succeed.. (See image).

Comment: I have tried separating it with the top part in the pre-logic script code as well

Comment: you should tick a codeblock, insert first part `def "Range_one"(value1,value2):
    if value > 2 and value < 3.5:
        return value2
    else:
        return 0`  in a first window and insert `Range_one (!ORG_STOF!,!Count_ORG_STOF!) ` in second window

Comment: Got it! I had to change the "Range_one", to calc, and then it worked. Thank you kind for your help everyone and have a good day